# Snackbar - Cannot set margin in snackbar

Tags: android, android-snackbar, snackbar

Snackbar margins are not working at all. I'm trying to set margins in all the 4 sides of the snackbar layout.

Coordinator Layout:

```
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) snackbarLayout.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.setMargins(layoutParams.leftMargin + 20,layoutParams.topMargin + 20,layoutParams.rightMargin + 20,layoutParams.bottomMargin + 20);
snackbarLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Frame Layout:

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) snackbarLayout.getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.setMargins(layoutParams.leftMargin + 20,layoutParams.topMargin + 20,layoutParams.rightMargin + 20,layoutParams.bottomMargin + 20);
snackbarLayout.getChildAt(0).setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

None of these methods are working, I'm using **AndroidX**, and testing on **AndroidQ**.

```
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
```

**Note: Frame layout method setting internal margin (inside the layout), but I want it to set on the outside.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I used `Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar` as my default theme and It worked!

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar">
```